# Vmware ESXi install error "multiboot could not setup the video subsystem"

Tags: vmware-esxi

I get a message when loading the ESXi installer, right after it initially loads modules, that "multiboot could not setup the video subsystem".  Then, the screen goes blank.  Usually, here the install screen is supposed to turn to a yellow background, while it is loading the ESXi installer.

I have to install ESXi via IPMI as this is a cloud provider.  I dont have physical access to the machine to plug in a monitor, as some Googling has suggested.

Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image: esxi install error]

The motherboard in this server is a SuperMicro X10DRU-i+, if that helps.  Also encountered this issue with a Supermicro PIO-618U-TR4T+-ST031 motherboard.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of ESXi?

Comment: ESXi 6.0 and 6.5

Comment: Have you tried to change the monitor/console display to one that supports 1024 x 768? http://plain-virt.blogspot.ca/2012/11/vsphere-5x-errors-installing-esxi-5x.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my super micro. The solution was to change the onboard graphicscard from legacy to EFI in the bios.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you would need to change the monitor/console display to one that support 1024 x 768 and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: How would you do this for an IPMI setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your Motherboard absolutely supports this, this error usually comes up when a monitor is connected and the monitor itself is limited to less than 1024x768..  or you have a real monitor connected but you are installing through IPMI..  its a very typical Supermicro only problem.  to fix it, unplug the monitor and install only via IPMI.

Answer (score 1):

```
Advanced/PCIe/PCI/PnP Configuration/Onboard Video Option ROM
```

At here, you should change this option from legacy to EFI

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was simply using a DVI video cable instead of a VGA->(DVI adapter) cable. However, I believe using the `ignoreHeadless=TRUE` boot flag would also work:
 https://talesfromthedatacenter.com/2016/02/esxi-6-install-stuck-on-relocating-modules-and-starting-up-the-kernel/